# How to create a dict in python from two List of Lists

Tags: python

I have this:

```
lists1 = [ [a,b], [c,d], [e,f] ]
```

and this :

```
lists2 = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
```

I need to create a dictionary like this:

```
{ a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6 }
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: [I downvoted because no attempt was made.](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: What have you tried and what difficulties have you run into?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack OverFlow! We appreciate your posting here :) but there are some guidelines to asking a question. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows -

```
lists1 = [ ['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f'] ]
lists2 = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]
 
dictionary = {}

# Loops through inner lists of both lists at same time - l1 for lists1 and l2 for lists2 
for l1,l2 in zip(lists1,lists2):
    # Loops through the elements of inner list of lists1 & lists2, that is l1 and l2
    for elem1,elem2 in zip(l1,l2):
        dictionary[elem1] = elem2   # Simply assign element from list1 as keys to corresponding elements from lists2
print(dictionary)
```

**Output :**

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
```

---

A more pythonic way of doing it would be as follows -

```
lists1 = [ ['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f'] ]
lists2 = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]

dictionary = {k:v for l1,l2 in zip(lists1,lists2) for k,v in zip(l1,l2)}
print(dictionary)
```

**Output :**

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
```

Comment: you could have reduced it to one line `{m: n for i, j in zip(lists1, lists2) for m, n in zip(i, j)}` but I am not sure this is the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @VishalSingh added that as well. I kept the first one because it is more understandable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this work for an arbitrary number of iterations instead of exactly 2, then you could use [`numpy`](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/)`.flatten()` to flatten the list.

```
import numpy as np

lists1 = [ [a,b], [c,d], [e,f] ]
lists2 = [ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6] ]

out = {}

for x, y in zip(np.array(lists1).flatten(), np.array(lists2).flatten()):
    out[x] = y
```

will produce an out of

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
```

Comment: Nice +1. You can also use `.ravel()`.